# Open source JavaFX 2.0 component libraries

Tags: java, open-source, javafx-2

Are there any good component libraries / repositories for JavaFX 2.0?

In particular I'm looking for open source projects that I might be able to use, learn from and contribute to.

Answer (score 13):

The best place to start looking is the [open source](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) of the platform itself.  Currently, just controls are open sourced, but over time more items will be added.  Join the mailing list on the linked page to get involved.

Next, you could try the the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) project.  Which aims to develop and incubate controls, components and extra bits in addition to, or as an alternative to, what is available in JavaFX.

Then, you also have projects like [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/) which examine interfacing JavaFX with various data source providers, [Grezi](https://bitbucket.org/bgoetzmann/grezi/wiki/Home) which is an experimental presentation framework using JavaFX, or you might want to checkout [JFX Flow](http://www.zenjava.com/jfx-flow/) which is a framework for developing JavaFX applications.

If you prefer programming the JavaFX API in other languages, you could look into the open source [ScalaFX](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) or [GroovyFX](https://github.com/groovyfx-project/groovyfx) projects.

The JavaFX [sample applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) such as Ensemble are sourced under a BSD license, so feel free to create your own JavaFX samples based on the frameworks those applications provide.

I am sure there are a bunch of other such projects which I have missed or will be formed over time.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX itself is partially open-source and welcome for contribution. 
See http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few that I found...

- [controlsfx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)
- [JideFx](http://www.jidesoft.com/blog/2013/06/06/jidefx-beta-release/)
- [JFxtras](http://jfxtras.org/)

And [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/community/3rd-party-1844355.html) is the official Oracle summary page for third party JavaFX tools.